# Assign value "" to window.location.href

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, url

I call a method from Ajax. The method returns string. After the method finishes, I need to redirect the url.

```
success: function (data) {
                    window.location.href = data;
            }
```

So, in the beginning the url is localhost:1111/Login/Index and everything works fine if data != "".
But, if data = "", then I want window.location.href to be localhost:1111/. Now, window.location.href is localhost:1111/Login. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the URL as follows:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data == "") {
        data = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    }
    window.location.href = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send url without the host and then use:

```
window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host +"/"+data
```